# Suppose for a region on a surface I can draw a "handle" can I cut the surface to reduce it's genus while leaving the region intact?

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, surfaces

Suppose I have a smooth orientable surface $Q$ and a compact region $R$ of $Q$.  Suppose there is a closed curve $C$ that divides R into two connected components $R_1,R_2$ but does not divide Q into separate regions.
Suppose there is a (smooth) curve $f$ with one endpoint in $R_1$, the other in $R_2$ and is otherwise disjoint from $R$.
Must there it be possible to find a closed curve in Q not intersecting R, that does not divide  Q into two separate regions?
Colloquially must it be possible to find a handle we can "cut" from our surface?

Figure below: Region $R$ in orange is a subset of our surface which is the torus. The curve $C$ in blue divides $R$ into $R_1$ and $R_2$. The red curve has as two endpoints on the boundaries of $R_1$ and $R_2$ respectively. The green curve, disjoint from $R$  does not divide $Q$\ $R$ into two disjoint regions.

[image]

Also anyone recommend a basic reference for learning how to prove this kind of thing?(smooth 2dimensional surfaces only focusing on genus and surface operations)  Basic topology by Armstrong is understandable but doesn't provide enough tools for this kind of thing.
Other textbooks go too far and go beyond 2 dimensions or are a bit too abstract.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question tbh. Are you asking whether there exists an arc $f$ in a closed surface $\Sigma$ of genus $1$ whose ends join a compact subsurface without separating it? Just pick an annulus $R$ inside $Q$ and an arc $f$ that joins the right boundary component to the left boundary component.

Comment: One idea I have is perform surgery along C to yield a surface $Q'$ of smaller genus.  Now since $R_1$ and $R_2$ are disjoint, there is a way to "cut" the surface $Q'$ into two smaller surfaces $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ whose genus's when summed up is at most that of $Q'$.  Now glue  $Q_1$ and $Q _2$ at $C$.  Since $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are disjoint, this produces a surface $Q"$ of genus at most the  sum of the genus's of $Q_1$ and  $Q_2$.  I feel this is intuitively true but I don't know how to rigorously prove that this can work.

Comment: @Zest  in general the genus need not be 1. Second the annulus must not intersect the region $R$. Even for genus 1 idk how to prove such an annulus exists.

Comment: What do you mean by "the annulus must not intersect the region $R$"? Just take the annulus as $R$. It's a compact subsurface of $Q$. You will always find an arc from one boundary component (which is just a circle) of $R$ to the other boundary component of $R$ since your surface $Q$ is connected.

Comment: @Zest  I am looking for a closed curve not intersecting the region R which does not divide the surface Q into two components.  Also the R is just a compact subsurface not necessarily an annulus.

Comment: You didn't say that the curve $f$ has to be closed. Still, see my answer in response.